# Set single value on pandas multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

With a single-index dataframe, we can use loc to get, set, and change values:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame()
>>> df.loc['A',1]=1
>>> df
     1
A  1.0
>>> df.loc['A',1]=2
>>> df.loc['A',1]
2.0
```

However, with a multiindex dataframe, loc can get and change values:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame([['A','B',1]])
>>> df=df.set_index([0,1])
>>> df.loc[('A','B'),2]
1
>>> df.loc[('A','B'),2]=3
>>> df.loc[('A','B'),2]
3
```

but setting them seems to fail:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame()
>>> df.loc[('A','B'),2]=3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 688, in __setitem__
    indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 630, in _get_setitem_indexer
    return self._convert_tuple(key, is_setter=True)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 754, in _convert_tuple
    idx = self._convert_to_indexer(k, axis=i, is_setter=is_setter)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1212, in _convert_to_indexer
    return self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis, raise_missing=True)[1]
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1266, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1308, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

Why is this, and what is the "right" way to use loc to set a single value in a multiindex dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fails because you don't have the correct number of levels in the MultiIndex.

You need to initialize an empty DataFrame with the correct number of levels, for example using [`pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html#pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays):

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[],[]])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=idx)

df.loc[('A','B'), 2] = 3
```

Output:

```
       2
A B  3.0
```